# cutting a string into several lines in bash

Tags: bash, cut

I want to take the path of the local directory and put each directory on the path in a different line. I've tried to do it using cut:

`pwd | cut -f 1- -d\/ --output-delimiter=\n`

but it doesn't change the '/'s into EOL, but puts n's instead.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
pwd | tr '/' '\n'
```

If you don't want an empty line in the beginning (due to the initial `/`) you could do

```
pwd | cut -b2- | tr '/' '\n'
```

**Example:**

```
#aioobe@r60:~/tmp/files$ pwd
/home/aioobe/tmp/files
#aioobe@r60:~/tmp/files$ pwd | cut -b2- | tr '/' '\n'
home
aioobe
tmp
files
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
pwd | tr '/' '\n'
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how you would accomplish what you set out to do (using ANSI-C quoting):

```
pwd | cut -f 1- -d\/ --output-delimiter=$'\n'
```